# Coloring the Natural Numbers

Tags: number-theory, graph-theory

This problem appears on page $134$ of Peter Winkler's *Mathematical Mind-Benders.*

> Can you color the natural numbers $\{0,1,2,\dots\}$ with finitely many colors, in such a way that the sum $x+y$ and the product $xy$ of any two whole numbers always have different colors?

This was unsolved at the time of writing.  Winkler says,

> Apparently a set of six numbers is known such that any two of them are the product and sum of some pair of numbers, so that at least six colors would be needed; on the other hand, there are not arbitrarily large sets of numbers with the above property.

I haven't been able to find six such numbers, though I admit I haven't tried very hard, but it's the statement that it is known that there are not arbitrarily large cliques that intrigues me.  I can't imagine how to attack a question like this.

I haven't been able to find anything about this on the Web.  Can you give me any information about the problem, and how to produce the results mentioned above?

Comment: Regarding the six numbers, do yo mean for example $2$ ($2+2=2\cdot 2$), $6$ ($1+2+3=1\cdot 2\cdot 3$),$\dots$ or not?

Comment: @Dog_69 We need $6$ numbers $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_6$ such that for any $i\ne j$, either $a_i = x+y \land a_j = xy$ or $a_i = xy \land a_j = x+y$ has a solution (showing that $a_i$ and $a_j$ need to have different colors).

Comment: It was not a help. I wanted to know if I had understood the question. Thanks and sorry.

Comment: @Dog_69 Sorry for the abrupt comment; rephrased.

Comment: It is not difficult to show that such a set cannot be infinite (use the fact that $a$ and $b$ are a sum and a product, respectively, iff $a^2 - 4b$ is a square; given any $a$ and $b$ in the set, only finitely many integers will work with both of them), but establishing a bound on the maximum size seems tricky.

Comment: It's OK, don't worry. Good luck with the answer.

Comment: @FredH Thank you.  This seems so simple, but I'm sure I would never have come up with it.  Indeed, I've been thinking about this problem off and on for several weeks, and never got a glimmer.

Comment: @FredH On second thought, while you've shown there can't be an infinite clique, this argument does't dispose of the possibility that there are arbitrarily large finite cliques, right?

Comment: Right, that's the tricky part.